# Laravel Login and Registration, User wont get into database

Tags: php, laravel

So i am trying to do a Login and Registration system using Laravel Framwork. I dont get any errors when i run it but when i am trying to create a user it wont go into the database.
Here is my function.

```
 public function postRegister()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $rules = array("username" => "required|unique:users|email", "password" => "required");
        $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);
        if($v->passes())
        {
            $user = new User();
            $password = $input["password"];
            $password = Hash::make($password);
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $input["username"];
            $user->email = $input["email"];
            $user->password = $password;
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to("login");
            echo 'Succes, now you can log in!';

        } else{
            return Redirect::to("register");
            echo 'Someting went wrong, try again!';
        }
    }
```

And here you can see my `register.blade`

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'register')) }}
            <h1>Register</h1>

            <!-- if there are login errors, show them here -->
            @if (Session::get('registerError'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ Session::get('registerError') }}</div>
            @endif

            <p>
                {{ $errors->first('username') }}
                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
                {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('placeholder' => 'Choose Username')) }}
            </p>


            <p>
                {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}
                {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('placeholder' => 'awesome@awesome.com')) }}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
                {{ Form::password('password') }}
            </p>

            <p>{{ Form::submit('Register') }}</p>
            <p>{{HTML::link("login", "Back to login")}}</p>
        {{ Form::close() }}

    </body>
    </html>
```

Maybe I am just missing something!

Comment: Remove double `$user = new User();` for sure

Comment: whoops! but it still doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Print out input with `print_r(Input::all())` (remember to comment out returns) and see if post data is passed to that function. It it is, the controller is wrong, if not, theres something wrong in view.

Comment: yeah okey still doesnt solve the problem about the user not going in to the database when i register.

Comment: You're echoing content after a return, which would never see the light of day. The return statement tells PHP to end execution of this method and continue down the chain, so if there was an error with validation, you'd never know.

Comment: @user3207299 but what did that print_r showed you? Was it blank or was it ok with all post data?

Comment: Its works now! it was another problem! :) thanks anyways!